# how can I "help along" node's garbage collection when dealing with large arrays?

Tags: node.js, memory, coffeescript, garbage-collection, v8

I have about 5 very large csv files that I need to parse, munge and insert into a database. The code looks approximately like this:

```
i = 0 

processFile = (linecount, file, onDone) ->
  # process the csv as a stream 
  # NOTE: **this is where the large array gets declared**
  # insert every relevant line into an array 
  # process the array and insert it into the db (about 5k records at a time) 
  # call onDone when db insert is done 

getLinesAndProcess = (i, onDone) ->
  inputFile = inputFiles[i]
  if inputFile?
    getFileSizeAndProcess =  -> # this helps the GC
      puts = (error, stdout, stderr) ->
        totalLines = stdout.split(" ")[0]
        processFile(totalLines, inputFile, ->
          getLinesAndProcess(++i)
        )
        console.log "processing: #{inputFile}"
      exec "wc -l '#{inputFile}'", puts

    setTimeout(getFileSizeAndProcess, 5000)

getLinesAndProcess(i, ->
  # close db connection, exit process and so on
)
```

The first million lines go fine, takes about 3 mins. Then it chunks along on the next record -- until node hits its memory limit (1.4GB) then it *just crawls*. The most likely thing is that v8's GC is not cleaning up the `recordsToInsert` array, even though it's in a closure that is done.

My solution in the short term is to just run one file at a time. That's fine, it works and so on, but I'm stuck with what to do to fix the multi-file problem. I've tried the `-–max-old-space-size=8192` [fix from caustik's blog](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/11/escape-the-1-4gb-v8-heap-limit-in-node-js/), but it hasn't helped -- node is still getting stuck at 1.4GB. I added in the `setTimeout` based on a suggestion in another SO post. It doesn't appear to help.

In the end, I just had to set the array back to an empty array before calling the callback. That works fine but it feels like v8's GC is failing me here.

Can I do anything to get v8 to be smarter about GC when dealing with large arrays?

Comment: One of the reasons it slows down after 1.4GB (as stated in the link you sent) is the V8 GC, triggers when the amount of allocated memory since last GC, exceeds external allocation limit. You may want to try `V8/heap-inl.h` hack as well.

Comment: Blech, compiling v8 sounds like a rabbit hole. I've tried dealing with compiling v8 to get the profiler to work and it sucked.

Comment: The code you're missing is probably important.  Specifically, what `processFile` does (you can leave out business logic, but how you're reading the file and such would help), and how you're looping over the 5 files.

Answer (score 0):

Closed over variables just seem like this because syntactically they *look* like local variables which live on the stack.

However they are *very, very different.*

If you had object like this:

```
function Closure() {
    this.totalLines = [];
    this.otherVariable = 3;
}

var object = new Closure();
```

Majority of people would understand that `totalLines` will never be garbage collected as long as `object` lives on. And if they were done with `totalLines` long before they were done with the object, they would assign it to `null` or at least understand that the garbage collector cannot collect it.

However, when it comes to actual javascript closures it works exactly the same yet people find it odd that they would have to explicitly set the closed over variable to null because the syntax is deceiving them.

Comment: In the given code, the closure all gets recycled at the expected time (keep in mind that coffeescript `var`s variables at the appropriate time).  This is a good point, but unless you know something about the code that isn't in the question, there's no reason to believe that's the problem in this case.